# pywinauto: cant access menubar

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

Application: desktop, design software

platform: windows 10

Pywinauto: pywinauto==0.6.8

Python 3.9.7

Problem statement: when trying to access menubar, using menu_select or other means getting error.

```
app = application.Application(backend="uia").start('some application.exe', timeout=120)
dlg = app.Sheet
dlg.wait('visible')
dlg.WorkspacePane.wait('visible')
dlg.dump_tree()

   | Pane - 'Menu Bar'    (L-1, T24, R1919, B49)
   | ['Menu Bar', 'Menu BarPane', 'Pane4']
   | child_window(title="Menu Bar", auto_id="59647", control_type="Pane")
```

[image]

not able to access, click the menu bar contents: eg: File, Edit, etc

Using tools, like inspect.exe, shows "no children"